# Disable (not hide) system UI bar programmatically on non-rooted 4.0+ android tablet?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In my app, there is a activity where it is important that the system UI buttons (home, back, etc.) are not pressed, though it is ok if they are still visible. I have heard that there might be a way to achieve this, at least in 4.0 (I'm using 4.2).

A way to quickly and automatically return to the app if the buttons are pressed is also a correct answer, but seems less plausible. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing can override the home button in non-rooted devices. Except for Jon Skeet of course.

Comment: @wtsang02: Well, that's because [Jon Skeet has root access to your system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9135/161639).

Comment: @Lableable: if there's a way to block these, that represents a security flaw and will hopefully get fixed.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it a security flaw beyond having to reboot (?) to exit an app that hides it and doesn't provide a button for exiting? Is this a security problem for rooted devices generally?

Comment: "is it a security flaw beyond having to reboot (?) to exit an app that hides it and doesn't provide a button for exiting?" -- IMHO, yes. "Is this a security problem for rooted devices generally?" -- if you root your device, you have already decided to take security into your own hands.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to override the home button by making your activity as home activity i.e 
-- category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"

but in this case android give user option to choose the app on launcher dialog where if user choose your application and click always, he will not be able to go to homescreen until you specifically provide a exit button oinside your app and reset it which you should definately do.